# Can I replace "but" with "while" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

As I was reading a sample essay in preparation for my upcoming exam, I wondered if I can change the conjunction in this sentence to make it sound more right and more logical - I think the two clauses are things happening at the same time instead of something contrasting with the former.

> I do not think that either nature or nurture is the major influence on a person, **but** that both have powerful effects.

Comment: It sounds funny in my head, I wouldn't imagine it would fit in unless you perhaps reworked the sentence.

Comment: Separate sentences are probably best to avoid the awkward "I don't choose either A or B, but both." << I do not think that either nature or nurture is **the** major influence on a person. No, I think that _both_ have powerful effects. >>

Comment: No, the 'but that' is a phrase.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is currently written as a negation :

> I do not think [*this*] but [I think *that*]

Straight substitution could sound confused and appear less right and less logical - as if you had two conflicting thoughts (even though the substance of the thoughts is identical). If you wanted to use "while", the sentence could be written :

> Some people think that either nature or nurture is the major influence
>   on a person, while I think that both have powerful effects.

So the simultaneous event is different people having different thoughts.

Or you could do without the conjunction :

> I do not think that either nature or nurture is the major influence on
>   a person. I think that both have powerful effects.

Having a separate sentence for each thought avoids the simultaneous "*this* is wrong and *that* is right" which, even if *this* and *that* are different, is expressing both agreement and disagreement in the same sentence - though "*this* is wrong but *that* is right" doesn't have the same problem as it is already a negation.